# Dismiss post-flag popup when moving on to next post

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, review

Can we have the post-flagging modal popup automatically dismissed when we click the "I'm done" button while reviewing First Posts?

The popup is no longer relevant once the next post is loaded and therefore serves no purpose.

Sure we can click the popup to dismiss it (and it will eventually disappear after a timeout), but that extra click is a minor inconvenience especially when I'm in the groove and eating NAA's for breakfast.

Comment: The same happens with the post close vote popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. All notification popups are automatically dismissed upon advancing to the next item in the review queue.