# Late Answers Review: "Thanks, we'll take a look at it!" hangs around after "I'm Done"

Tags: feature-request, flags, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dismiss post-flag popup when moving on to next post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147059/dismiss-post-flag-popup-when-moving-on-to-next-post)

[image]

After flagging an answer, the red "Thanks, we'll take a look at it!" box appears. This is normal. However, it remains around after clicking "I'm Done" and overlays the next answer. I feel this behavior is confusing, as one might think that the *next* answer had been flagged.

I would suggest that this popup be automatically cleared if it is still present when "I'm Done" is clicked.

Comment: This happens also with the dialog box informing you how much votes to close are still necessary, once you vote to close a question.